# How you can have min and max values for zooming into layout

Tags: android, pinchzoom

I have the following which allows me to zoom in and out indefinitely, however I am trying to set a `min` and `max` value for zoom so that the layout is not too large or too small. I have tried to use but I just don't understand where to place this in the code.

```
private static final float MIN_ZOOM = 1.0f;
private static final float MAX_ZOOM = //set Maximum zooming level
float scale = Math.max(MIN_ZOOM, Math.min(scale, MAX_ZOOM));

public class ZoomableView extends RelativeLayout {

    // States.
    private static final byte NONE = 0;
    private static final byte DRAG = 1;
    private static final byte ZOOM = 2;

    private byte mode = NONE;

    // Matrices used to move and zoom image.
    private Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    private Matrix matrixInverse = new Matrix();
    private Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();

    // Parameters for zooming.
    private PointF start = new PointF();
    private PointF mid = new PointF();
    private float oldDist = 1f;
    private float[] lastEvent = null;
    private long lastDownTime = 0l;

    private float[] mDispatchTouchEventWorkingArray = new float[2];
    private float[] mOnTouchEventWorkingArray = new float[2];


    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        mDispatchTouchEventWorkingArray[0] = ev.getX();
        mDispatchTouchEventWorkingArray[1] = ev.getY();
        mDispatchTouchEventWorkingArray = screenPointsToScaledPoints(mDispatchTouchEventWorkingArray);
        ev.setLocation(mDispatchTouchEventWorkingArray[0], mDispatchTouchEventWorkingArray[1]);
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    public ZoomableView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public ZoomableView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public ZoomableView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context);
    }


    private void init(Context context) {

    }


    /**
     * Determine the space between the first two fingers
     */
    private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
        return (float) Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

    /**
     * Calculate the mid point of the first two fingers
     */
    private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
        point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
    }

    private float[] scaledPointsToScreenPoints(float[] a) {
        matrix.mapPoints(a);
        return a;
    }

    private float[] screenPointsToScaledPoints(float[] a) {
        matrixInverse.mapPoints(a);
        return a;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        int childCount = getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            if (child.getVisibility() != GONE) {
                child.layout(left, top, left + child.getMeasuredWidth(), top + child.getMeasuredHeight());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        int childCount = getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            if (child.getVisibility() != GONE) {
                measureChild(child, widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        float[] values = new float[9];
        matrix.getValues(values);
        canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(values[Matrix.MTRANS_X], values[Matrix.MTRANS_Y]);
        canvas.scale(values[Matrix.MSCALE_X], values[Matrix.MSCALE_Y]);
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // handle touch events here
        mOnTouchEventWorkingArray[0] = event.getX();
        mOnTouchEventWorkingArray[1] = event.getY();

        mOnTouchEventWorkingArray = scaledPointsToScreenPoints(mOnTouchEventWorkingArray);

        event.setLocation(mOnTouchEventWorkingArray[0], mOnTouchEventWorkingArray[1]);

        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                mode = DRAG;
                lastEvent = null;
                long downTime = event.getDownTime();
                if (downTime - lastDownTime < 300l) {
                    float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
                    if (Math.max(Math.abs(start.x - event.getX()), Math.abs(start.y - event.getY())) < 40.f * density) {
                        savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                        mid.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                        mode = ZOOM;
                        lastEvent = new float[4];
                        lastEvent[0] = lastEvent[1] = event.getX();
                        lastEvent[2] = lastEvent[3] = event.getY();
                    }
                    lastDownTime = 0l;
                } else {
                    lastDownTime = downTime;
                }
                start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                oldDist = spacing(event);
                if (oldDist > 10f) {
                    savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                    midPoint(mid, event);
                    mode = ZOOM;
                }
                lastEvent = new float[4];
                lastEvent[0] = event.getX(0);
                lastEvent[1] = event.getX(1);
                lastEvent[2] = event.getY(0);
                lastEvent[3] = event.getY(1);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                mode = NONE;
                lastEvent = null;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                final float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
                if (mode == DRAG) {
                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    float dx = event.getX() - start.x;
                    float dy = event.getY() - start.y;
                    matrix.postTranslate(dx, dy);
                    matrix.invert(matrixInverse);
                    if (Math.max(Math.abs(start.x - event.getX()), Math.abs(start.y - event.getY())) > 20.f * density) {
                        lastDownTime = 0l;
                    }
                } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                    if (event.getPointerCount() > 1) {
                        float newDist = spacing(event);
                        if (newDist > 10f * density) {
                            matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                            float scale = (newDist / oldDist);
                            matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                            matrix.invert(matrixInverse);
                        }
                    } else {
                        matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                        float scale = event.getY() / start.y;
                        matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                        matrix.invert(matrixInverse);
                    }
                }
                break;
        }

        invalidate();
        return true;
    }


}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to make a class extending RelativeLayout , there you can set it by overriding the `getMaxZoomLevel()` and `getMinZoomLevel()`, like this:

```
public class ZoomableView extends RelativeLayout {

@Override
public int getMaxZoomLevel() {
    return 22;
}

@Override
public int getMinZoomLevel() {
    return 12;
}

}
```

Comment: Hi Feras, thank you for your comment. I understand how to implement what you have told me to but I am not sure exactly where the values 22 and 12 would go. Should I create an if statement for the min and max values? - if so how would I say if the max is 22, stop  zooming in?